# Integer to ASCII conversion

Tags: apex, string, conversion, character-encoding

I'm trying to convert an integer into its corresponding ascii value but getting different result than what I get in java.

**Java**

```
int c = 5032;
char c1 = (char)c;
System.out.print('==>' + c1);
//output ==> ?
```

**Apex**

```
string str = String.fromCharArray(new Integer[]{5032});
system.debug('==>' + str);
//output ==> Ꭸ
```

I believe java output is correct one, how can I achieve that same result in Apex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java and Apex you are dealing with 16 bit characters (Unicode/UTF-16) not 8 bit characters (such as ASCII). Character 5032 in Unicode is this http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/5032/index.htm. (Some more detail in [How does Java store UTF-16 characters in its 16-bit char type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112435/how-does-java-store-utf-16-characters-in-its-16-bit-char-type).)

As you can imagine, supporting many thousands of character glyphs in a font is a lot of work: the output you are seeing for Java may just be an output representing the lack of a glyph in the font being used. The output you see in Apex is probably more correct.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the [ASCII Code](http://www.ascii-code.com/) for the question mark character (`?`) is 63.

```
system.assertEquals('?', String.fromCharArray(new List<Integer> { 63 }));
```

Also, it does look like 5032 should correspond to the character output by `Apex`, according to [this page](http://www.andmine.com/ascii-codes-html-table-reference/index.php?start=5000).

Answer (score 1):

In Apex Code and Java, strings are stored in UTF-8. The difference comes in the output of those characters (System.out vs System.debug). If you wrote the output to a file, and set the encoding to UTF-8, they should come out to be the same output. It's a matter of the stream's interpretation. Java, by default, outputs ASCII, while Apex Code always uses UTF-8. Technically, Java's output is incorrect, because it did not display the correct glyph for the specified character. If you were to use that same char in a string that were displayed in a GUI, there should be no difference between Java and Apex Code's output.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially both your java and apex code are giving the right output.
Java system.out.print to a console does not interpret the UTF-16 char, hence a "?". But now if you spool the char to a file(OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF16");) in your Java Code, you can see the right Unicode character.
Apex "system.debug" spools the output to a file (Unicode), hence you see the expected Unicode char.